# Can't link IBOutlet to XIB File XCode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib, iboutlet

I've been following a tutorial on how to create a custom info window for the Google Maps SDK and when I try to connect the UILabel declarations in the obj-c file to the labels in the XIB file, nothing happens. I can't even connect the labels in the XIB file to the interface declaration and create them that way. Here's a link to an image of my setup:

[image]

Is this a bug with the new version of XCode or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Go to Identity inspector and make sure that you conect your .xib with proper class.

[image]

You should have there CustomInfoWindow

Comment: Good to hear it :) so now, you can tag my answer as correct one

Comment: I have that and I can't drag from files owner